# Are there customizations available for pasting images or screenshots to wiki

Tags: wiki

I would like to copy an image to a SharePoint wiki as easily as I can copy it to a word document - for example, pasting a screenshot to a wiki, getting asked for the file name, and getting the image saved to the default image library with img tag generated.

I would like to have interoperability with future SP versions (continue relying on oob SP wikis without extensions if no need for this in SP15).

Comment: I want that too

Comment: I think we all want that....

Comment: Are there some real showstoppers for implementing this? The solution does not have to be cross browser. event.clipboardData is supported by Chrome.

Comment: if include all your criteria - it's impossible.
Sorry.